# How to send multiple files and json data with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, file

Hi I'm new to file upload.I've written an api that can get multiple file and file name and and id to save it to database.It is working fine with Postman and I'm uploading files without issue.In form-data I use a file with the key named "multifileupload" and a key named "picturetitle" and another key named "appointid".It uploads,and i've read many tutorials and still confused how to send multiple files with one input and some other data as i'm testing with postman.

My Html Code:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p>
                <label>Add files (multiple): </label><br/>
                <input id="fileInput" type="file" name="example3[]" multiple="multiple"/>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input id="sendFileSubmit" type="submit"/>
            </p>
        </form>
```

Jquery:

```
    $(document).on("click","#sendFileSubmit",function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var picturetitle = "testtitle";
        var appointid = 64;
        var fd = new FormData();
        var files = $('#fileInput')[0].files[0];
        fd.append('file',files);

        $.ajax({
            url: '../public/index.php/api/files/uploadfile',
            type: 'post',
            headers:{
                authorization:cookie
            },
            data:{
                multifileupload:fd,
                picturetitle:picturetitle,
                appointid:appointid
            },
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(result){
                console.log(result)
            },
        });
    });
```

PHP Slim Server Side Code:

```
$app->post('/uploadfile',function(Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
            $decodedsenttoke = $request->getAttribute('decoded_token_data');
            $directory = $this->get('upload_directory');
            $uploadedFiles = $request->getUploadedFiles();
            $fileCount = 0;
            foreach ($uploadedFiles['multifileupload'] as $uploadedFile) {
                if ($uploadedFile->getError() === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                    $pathOfUploadedFiles = "http://example.com/uploads/";
                    $filename = moveUploadedFile($directory, $uploadedFile);
                    $pathOfUploadedFiles .= $filename;
                    $input = $request->getParsedBody();
                    $insertsql = "INSERT INTO
files (picturelink   ,  picturetitle ,  appointid )
 VALUES    (:picturelink  , :picturetitle , :appointid )";
                    $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, 'SET NAMES utf8');
                    $sth = $this->db->prepare($insertsql);
                    $sth->bindParam("picturelink", $pathOfUploadedFiles);
                    $sth->bindParam("picturetitle", $input['picturetitle']);
                    $sth->bindParam("appointid", $input['appointid']);
                    try{
                        $sth->execute();
                        $fileCount++;
                    } catch(PDOException $e){
                        echo '{"error":{"text":'.$e->getMessage().'}';
                    }
                }
            }
            $insertArray = array('message'=>'inserted' , 'numberOfUploadedfiles'=>$fileCount);
            return $this->response->withJson($insertArray);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

There's two issues here. Firstly you only append the first file in the input to the FormData object. As it's a `multiple` you need to loop through all the files. This can be done manually or, as the input is in a `form`, you can simply provide a reference of that form to the FormData constructor and it will do the work for you. The only caveat here is that you will change the `name` of the input to match the key of the object, as I presume this is the argument name the server side logic is expecting.

Secondly you're attempting to send the FormData through an object with other data. The correct approach is the inverse; add the other data to the FormData object and send that only. Try this:

```js
$('#yourForm').on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var picturetitle = "testtitle";
  var appointid = 64;
  
  var fd = new FormData(this);
  fd.append('picturetitle', picturetitle);
  fd.append('appointid', appointid);

  $.ajax({
    url: '../public/index.php/api/files/uploadfile',
    type: 'post',
    headers: { authorization: cookie },
    data: fd,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(result) {
      console.log(result)
    },
  });
});
```

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="yourForm">
  <p>
    <label>Add files (multiple): </label><br/>
    <input id="fileInput" type="file" name="multifileupload" multiple="multiple" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input id="sendFileSubmit" type="submit" />
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm getting the error "Call to a member function getError() on string" on line 
`foreach ($uploadedFiles['multifileupload'] as $uploadedFile)`

Comment: I can't really help with that as I'm not a PHP dev. I'd suggest starting a new question about the server side logic, as this question was about how to send the data from the client.

Comment: thanks But I'm testing the server side with postman and it's working properly

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to upload the files one by one. I did in this way and it works for me.

```js
$(document).on("click", "#sendFileSubmit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var picturetitle = "testtitle";
  var appointid = 64;
  var files = $('#fileInput')[0].files[0];
  for (var f = 0; f < files.length; f++) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', files[f]);
    $.ajax({
      url: '../public/index.php/api/files/uploadfile',
      type: 'post',
      headers: {
        authorization: cookie
      },
      data: {
        multifileupload: fd,
        picturetitle: picturetitle,
        appointid: appointid
      },
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(result) {
        console.log(result)
      },
    });
  }
});
```